# What is the default binning method of Histogram[]?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, histograms, default

Histogram[] command returns a histogram of a set of data. There are different methods of binning, such as, Scott's rule, which we can specify the binning method in Mathematica. My question is what is the default method if we simply use Histogram[] without mentioning any methods?

**Edit**

my data is

```
data = {1.13844, 1.10109, 1.03831, 1.02489, 1.16765, 0.912923, 1.01457, 1.03019, 0.952638, 1.07414, 1.07064, 1.12457, 2.06135, 1.51554, 1.00305, 1.28597, 1.07314, 1.07414, 1.27367, 1.25106, 1.1908, 1.13045, 1.77163, 0.968733, 1.15431, 2.19873, 1.21677, 1.18097, 1.17156, 1.14869, 1.0507, 1.03325, 1.15629, 1.12532, 1.13168, 1.26833, 1.17635, 1.4219, 1.00932, 0.903098, 1.00712, 1.3277, 1.23269, 1.26672, 1.07351, 1.04526, 1.08045, 1.22098, 1.03523, 0.972292, 1.61186, 1.23884, 1.179, 1.02588, 1.22071, 1.19235, 1.00152, 1.22573, 1.37772, 1.32637, 0.98045, 1.43544, 1.10864, 1.16715, 1.21744, 1.04416, 1.39065, 1.11793, 0.934261, 1.01806, 0.93414, 0.98045, 1.33027, 1.04526, 1.22946, 1.3379, 1.03945, 1.04202, 2.09368, 1.02489, 1.00827, 0.980572, 1.441, 1.16803, 0.89296, 1.41903, 1.13819, 1.00693, 1.15289, 0.90875, 0.96885, 0.947454, 1.21061, 1.00212, 1.05155, 0.973319, 1.21225, 1.00321, 1.03475, 1.06212, 1.28291, 1.2973, 1.10623, 0.869565, 1.06734, 0.930803, 1.00827, 1.29888, 1.31592, 1.2139, 1.32063, 1.00152, 0.891578, 1.11041, 0.888591, 1.07351, 1.04348, 1.16182, 1.14529, 1.08984, 0.981955, 1.2804, 1.25552, 1.31727, 1.20127, 1.16135, 1.01093, 1.07603, 1.10281, 1.32891, 1.09263, 1.29426, 1.28252, 1.15548, 1.06734, 0.931554, 1.03059, 1.06839, 1.09821, 3.26991, 1.11641, 1.13194, 1.02992, 1.19928, 2.36354, 1.1669, 2.11511, 2.21763, 0.886074, 1.21061, 1.1669, 1.19272, 1.36954, 1.20551, 1.28695, 0.978261, 1.49234, 1.18277}
```

Here is the default histogram:

```
Histogram[data]
```

[image]

which Mathematica, for some unknown reasons, has chosen the Freedman-Diaconis rule:

```
Histogram[data, "FreedmanDiaconis"]
```

For each set of data, the default command, Histogram[], guesses the specific method of binning. But how does it so? In other words, can one trust the default command? (At least, it seems it does not do the binning blindly by some fixed method of binning, and for each case it treats the problem differently.)

Comment: *Mathematica* essentially uses Sturges Rule but with some "nice" rounding of the bin delimiters.  The number of bins will be close to `Floor[1 + Log[2, n] + 0.5]`.  So `HistogramList[data]` will give the same results as `HistogramList[data, "Sturges"]`.

Comment: I now agree.  I tried it with data with a normal distribution and it always matched with using `"Sturges"`.  However, with a uniform distribution it does not match.  So it must also depend on the data.  I will now shut up and wait for someone who really knows.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: "can one trust the default command" What do you mean by "trust"? Trust to do what?

Answer (score 1):

Two steps of spelunking reveals that the default binning method is `"Scott"`:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

PrintDefinitions[Histogram]
```

[image]

```
DefaultValues[System`HistogramDump`iHistogramLayer1]
```

[image]

Verification:

```
SeedRandom[1]
And @@ (Histogram[#][[1]] == Histogram[#, "Scott"][[1]] & /@ 
   Table[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], 500], 50])
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
And @@ (Histogram[#][[1]] == Histogram[#, "Scott"][[1]] & /@ 
   Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 500], 50])
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
And @@ (Histogram[#][[1]] == Histogram[#, "Scott"][[1]] & /@ 
   Table[RandomVariate[MixtureDistribution[{2, 1}, 
         {NormalDistribution[], NormalDistribution[2, 1/2]}], 500], 50])
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: @Nima, good question. [HistogramList >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramList.html) says _HistogramList[
  data] by default gives equal bins chosen to approximate an assumed underlying smooth distribution of the values {xi, yi, ...}._  It seems that further processing of input data  leads to a non-default binning method.

Comment: @Nima, ``??Histogram`HistogramListDump`HistogramWandBinning`` gives the definition for `"Wand"` binning.